# Get first name and last name of User.identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Intranet application set up with Windows Authentication.
I need to display in the header the username and the user's initials, for example:

> Welcome jSmith **JS**

What I did so far:

```
<div class="header__profile-name">Welcome <b>@User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]</b></div>
<div class="header__profile-img">@User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].Substring(0, 2)</div>
```

The issue is that the username is not **always** the first letter of the first name + the last name, sometimes the username can be the first name + the first letter of the last name for ex:

> John Smith - the username **can** be *jsmith* but sometimes it can also
>   be: *johns*

In that case my code is wrong because it will result:

> *jo* instead of *js*

How can I get the full user name: first name and last name with `User.identity`?

Then I'll base my code on the full user name (first and last name) in order to set up the initials and not on the username that is not always consistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the ApplicationUser class, you'll notice a comment (if you use the standard MVC5 template) that says "Add custom user claims here".

Given that, here's what adding FullName would look like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", this.FullName));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Using this, when someone logs in, the FullName claim will be put in the cookie. You could make a helper to access it like this:

```
public static string GetFullName(this System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal usr)
{
    var fullNameClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)usr.Identity).FindFirst("FullName");
    if (fullNameClaim != null)
        return fullNameClaim.Value;

    return "";
}
```

**Update**

**Or** you could add it to the User's claims when you create the user and then retrieve it as a claim from the User.Identity:

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("FullName", user.FullName));
```

Retreive it:

```
((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("FullName")
```

Or you could just fetch the user and access it off of the user.FullName directly:

```
var user = await userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
return user.FullName
```

**Update**

for `intranet` You can do something like this:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
    var firstName = principal.GivenName;
    var lastName = principal.Surname;
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly.

You can add a Razor helper like so:

```
@helper AccountName()
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname
    }
}
```

If you indend on doing this from the view, rather than the controller, you need to add an assembly reference to your web.config as well:

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
```

Add that under `configuration/system.web/assemblies`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where can I find the `ApplicationUser` class? I don't create the user, I'm using the _intranet_ template.

Comment: @user3378165 You should make it `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` . But secend way is better

Comment: Thank you, I saw these answers online but that doesn't answer my question, I'm using the ready windows authentication template so I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user3378165 You want to get the full name of a user in intranet app?

Comment: Yes, intranet app with Windows Authentication

Comment: Thank you, that works (with a few minor changes- I obviously had to add the reference, on `web.config` the referance shoud be added under: `configuration/system.web/compilation/assemblie` and the helper method should be called like that: `@AccountName()`). But that results the first and last name concatenated, how can I add a space between them?

Comment: @user3378165  Insert "&nbsp;" to add more blank spaces.`<text>&nbsp;</text>`

Comment: @user3378165 I'm glad that helped you.

Comment: Its wonderful answer, what i was looking for, is the section about the intranet user update section. thank you!