# First name and last name from claimprincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to get first name and last name from `ClaimPrincipal`.

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name; 
var fullNameClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("FullName"); // Doesn't give output
```

Using this I get the name of the logged in user. Is there any way to get first name and last name from claim principal.

Comment: That entirely depends on if you are putting first and last name claims into the token.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.FindFirst(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.findfirst?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity_FindFirst_System_String_) method retrieves the first claim with the specified claim type.

If it's returning `null` then no claims match the type that was provided.

You have to make sure you add a claim with the `FullName` type before attempting to find it.

Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943909/get-first-name-and-last-name-of-user-identity) on how to create the `FullName` property, user [@Hossein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4588756/hossein) did a really good breakdown on where and how to add the claim in order to access it later.